# Passing an options argument to the httpClient.post method doesn't always compile

Tags: angular

Why can't I pass the options argument to the `httpClient.post<T>` method call ?

The following code doesn't compile when I uncomment the second return line :

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttpService {

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    public postWithHeaders<T>(url: string, body: string, headers?: HttpHeaders | null): Observable<T> {
        const options = {
            headers: this.prepareHeader(headers),
            observe: 'response' as 'body', // Have the response headers included in the response object
            responseType: 'json'
        };
        return this.httpClient.post<T>(url, body, this.prepareHeader(headers));
        // return this.httpClient.post<T>(url, body, options); why I cannot have this line instead of the above one ?
    }

    private prepareHeader(headers: HttpHeaders | null): object {
        headers = headers || new HttpHeaders();
        headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers = headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
        return headers;
    }

}
```

This is all the more puzzling when I can have in another class the following source code that compiles just fine :

```
  public login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    console.log('Sending the login credentials to obtain a token');
    const credentials = { 'email' : username, 'password' : password };
    // Have the response headers included in the response object
    const options = {
      observe: 'response' as 'body'
    };
    const url: string = environment.USER_REST_URL + '/login';
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(url, credentials, options);
  }
```

The vscode IDE shows the following compile issue :

```
[ts]
L'argument de type '{ headers: object; observe: "body"; responseType: string; }' n'est pas attribuable au paramètre de type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
  Les types de la propriété 'headers' sont incompatibles.
    Impossible d'assigner le type 'object' au type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
      Impossible d'assigner le type 'object' au type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
        Signature d'index manquante dans le type '{}'.
const options: {
    headers: object;
    observe: "body";
    responseType: string;
}
```

And the console shows the following issue :

```
ERROR in src/app/core/service/custom-http.service.ts(17,51): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ headers: object; observe: "body"; responseType: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
  Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
    Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
      Type 'object' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
        Index signature is missing in type '{}'.
```

The issue has nothing to do with the headers. Even if removing the `headers` property from the options object, the issue remains the same.

UPDATE: The issue was indeed related to the `headers` property. Having the `prepareHeader` method return type to `HttpHeaders` fixed the issue. Why didn't the IDE reflect this when I tried that before I cannot explain.

I'm under Angular `6.0.4`.

Comment: What does `prepareHeader` return ?

Comment: It's a compile time error. It instantiate in its body and returns a `HttpHeaders` object. The issue comes when I uncomment the second return statement and comment out the first one.

Comment: Can you show also you error? It is regarding to the types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, the return type of `prepareHeader()` is `object`. Change it to `HttpHeaders`. That is the reason compiler is throwing an error.

> Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header:
>   string]: string | string[]; }'.

Modify the return type to `HttpHeaders`

```
private prepareHeader(headers: HttpHeaders | null): HttpHeaders {
        headers = headers || new HttpHeaders();
        headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers = headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
        return headers;
}
```

Also modify the `observe` and `responseType` properties as follows.

```
const options = {
            headers: this.prepareHeader(headers),
            observe: 'response' as 'body', // Have the response headers included in the response object
            responseType: 'json' as 'json'
};
```

There is an open [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586) related to `observe` and `responseType` properties.

Comment: Again, the issue has nothing to do with the headers property. Even if I remove this property from the options object the issue remains the same.

Comment: You have above the full source code for the class. You could try to compile it in your IDE and you may then replicate the issue.

Comment: Please check the updated answer, There is an open issue related to this. Have a look at that and also the work around i have suggested in my answer.

Comment: The issue was indeed related to the `headers` property. Having the `prepareHeader` method return type to `HttpHeaders` fixed the issue. Why didn't the IDE reflect this when I tried that before I cannot explain.